# Unable to ssh into Centos VM (CentOS minimal ISO in virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, network-adapter, centos-7, sshd

I have installed Centos minimal ISO on virtualbox. I modified hosts.allow to allow ssh incoming connection. There is no firewall blocking ssh connections. I am able to ssh into the VM from the host after adding Port Forwading rule. I have enabled NAT. I tried Bridged Adapter setting too. I have changed ONBOOT from No to Yes for enp0s3. I get 10.0.2.15 ip address too. If someone knows the solution, please help.

[ssh output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VBVO.png)
[image: network configuration]

I am not able to ping the VM.

Comment: Show the output of `ssh -vvv` for verbose logging. Also show if you can ping the IP of the VM.

Comment: i have added ssh output to the question

Comment: I believe it is a VirtualBox problem. Please add a screen shot of your VirtualBox network configuration and add the details of your host OS.

Comment: Host OS is MacOS Mojave 10.14.5